# Set a path relative to $UserBaseDirectory in the option inspector

Tags: front-end, stylesheet

Is there a way to set a setting in the *option inspector* to a path that is relative to some global Mathematica variable?

I'm trying to set up a default stylesheet by setting `DefaultStyleDefinitions` to a style sheet located in `$UserBaseDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`. I need the setting to be independent of the path to `$UserBaseDirectory` because I'm using the same settings on different machines where my user's directory has different names. But setting it to a value containing `$UserBaseDirectory` didn't work.

Comment: I just found out that I can use a path like `"~/Library/Mathematica/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets/My Default.nb"` for that setting, which solves my problem as I only need this setting to work on OS X. But I would still be interested in an answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Mathematica* looks for style sheets in the folders specified by `StyleSheetPath` and this already includes

```
FrontEnd`FileName[{$UserBaseDirectory, "SystemFiles", "FrontEnd", "StyleSheets"}]
```

on my system.  So just change the setting of `DefaultStyleDefinitions` to the name of your style sheet.

The setting for `StyleSheetPath`shows how to construct file names from global variables in a cross-platform manner.

Comment: Something has changed, now it contains only one path and `ParentList`, whatever that is, and adding new directories doesn't help to find stylesheets there :-/